# Socialite, facebook auth redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app

Tags: facebook, oauth, laravel-socialite

I tried it on local, was working ok. When I deployed website and made the application live on facebook for developers it does not seem to work.

[image]

So I added the live domain and stuff 
So I have the redirect funtion which is:

```
public function redirect()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}
```

and than the service.php:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '******',
    'client_secret' => '******',
    'redirect' => 'https://example.com/callback',
],
```

And than you have the callback function which is something like this:

```
public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
{
    $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());
    auth()->login($user);
    return redirect()->to('/home');
}
```

Finally I get the date and register use in `SocialFacebookAccountService` and it works properly in the localhost `wamp` server. I don't think you will need it but I'm adding th `createOrgetuser` function code here:

```
public function createOrGetUser(ProviderUser $providerUser)
{
    $account = SocialFacebookAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
        ->whereProviderUserId($providerUser->getId())
        ->first();

    if ($account) {
        return $account->user;
    } else {

        $account = new SocialFacebookAccount([
            'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            'provider' => 'facebook'
        ]);

        $user = User::whereEmail($providerUser->getEmail())->first();
        $lastuser = User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
        $token = str_random(40);

        $userslug = new Slugify();
        $slug = $userslug->slugify($providerUser->getName());

        $slugcheck = User::where('slug', $slug)->exists();
        if ($slugcheck){
            $slug = $slug.$lastuser->id;
        }


        if (!$user) {

            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'username' => $slug.'fbuser',
                'password' => str_random(40),
                'token' => $token
            ]);


        }

        $account->user()->associate($user);
        $account->save();

        return $user;
    }
}
```

That is it. Facebook gives the error:

> This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

facebook URL is looking like:
***https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=612150382487763&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foddlayer.com%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=NfHDBomCH3BkLXHjkHUSSFHI8NOkq6vmpj3tJm79***

I think it's not supposed to have all these '%' signs and stuff. i would love to get some help. Thanks

Comment: Are you guys able to see the image? I couldn't make it work. But it's not neccesary. Just showing that I have example.com added as domain in  panel `facebook for developers`

Comment: The linked answer is not even laravel. The redirect url is added in a different manner in socialite and that is what im probably lacking on. Why are you trying to cause trouble for me